# Play 2 tweens in parallel with GSAP?

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap, timeline

Can someone briefly explain what is the best way to play 2 tweens/animations in parallel in the same timeline using **GSAP 3**?

Example:

```
tl = gsap.timeline();

tl
.to( 'EL1', 1, {
   prop: value,
})
.to( 'EL2', 1, {
   prop: value
}, '-=1');
```

I would do it this way: `'-=1'`. Do you all have a better solution for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, in GSAP 3 we don't recommend using the duration parameter. Instead, we recommend including the duration inside of the vars parameter so that you can use features like GSAP's [defaults functionality](https://greensock.com/3-release-notes#defaults). For more info on upgrading to GSAP 3, see [the migration guide](https://greensock.com/3-migration/). I left the duration out below for the sake of the question.

---

There are a lot of ways to make sure that two tweens start at the same time:

1. Often times I find that the easiest way to do this is to **use the `'<'` position parameter operator**. This causes a tween to start at the same start position as the last tween. For example:

   ```
   .to('EL1', { prop: value })
   .to('EL2', { prop: value }, '<')
   ```
2. **Use a label**. There are a couple of ways you could create a label:

   ```
   .to('EL1', { prop: value }, 'myLabel') // If the label doesn't exist, it will be created at the start of this tween
   .to('EL2', { prop: value }, 'myLabel') // Since the label exists already, this tween will be positioned with its start at the label
   ```

   Or explicitly create it:

   ```
   .add('myLabel') // .addLabel() also works
   .to('EL1', { prop: value }, 'myLabel') // If the label doesn't exist, it will be created at the start of this tween
   .to('EL2', { prop: value }, 'myLabel') // Since the label exists already, this tween will be positioned with its start at the label
   ```
3. **Use a relative offset**. This only works if you also use the duration of the previous tween also:

   ```
   .to('EL1', { prop: value })
   .to('EL2', { prop: value }, '-=1') // Assuming the duration of the previous tween is 1
   ```
4. **Use an explicit time** in the timeline. I pretty much only use this method when I want the tweens to start at the beginning of the timeline:

   ```
   .to('EL1', { prop: value })
   .to('EL2', { prop: value }, 0) // Number of seconds in the timeline to start at - can be any number
   ```
5. In some circumstances you might have multiple pre-made animations that you want to fire at the same time as part of a timeline. In that case you might want to **add a function that fires both at a particular time** like so:

   ```
   .add(() => {
     myAnim1.play();
     myAnim2.play();
   })
   ```

   Note that this approach doesn't actually add the tweens to the timeline, it just uses a function that's a part of the timeline to play the animations.

   You could instead add the tweens themselves to the timeline using two separate `.add()` calls. This is also what you should do if you want to *sequence* pre-made animations as part of a timeline. To position them, use the same approaches covered in the other points above.

   ```
   .add(myAnim1)
   .add(myAnim2, '<')
   ```

For more explanation see [the position parameter post](http://greensock.com/position-parameter/).

Comment: Thanks @ZachSaucier point **1** has already worked great.

Comment: 5. is works properly also it is very useful to make a lot of parallel animations if put them all to array

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `label` to identify a specific point of the timeline. See the [.add()](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline/add()) method.

```
tl = gsap.timeline();

tl
.add("anim_start", "+=0") // Here is your label.
.to( 'EL1', 1, {
   prop: value,
}, "anim_start")
.to( 'EL2', 1, {
   prop: value
}, "anim_start");
```

So those two tweens will start at the same moment.

You can even "delay" a whole set of tweens that are binded to that label... Like with "+=2" on the label (instead of on every tweens). ;)

And you can have one tween delayed relative the label too! Like with:

```
to( 'EL1', 1, {
   prop: value,
},"anim_start+=2");`
```